# Trouble deploying Rails 3.2.6 app with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, deployment, capistrano

I've setup my Linode VPS properly with nginx, passenger, ruby 1.9.3-p194, and rails 3.2.6.  I've built a simple Cap recipe (see below) which passes deploy:setup and deploy:check but fails on the assets precompile phase.  I would try to run the precompile by hand on the remote server but Cap rollsback so I can't do it.

The error looks like a PG error however I've tested a connection manually to the server based off my database.yml settings and it works perfect.  Any idea what this could be?

```
deploy.rb
require "bundler/capistrano"

server "50.116.25.145", :web, :app, :db, primary: true

set :application, "exigencad"
set :user, "deploy"
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :use_sudo, false

set :scm, "git"
set :repository, "git@github.com:teknull/#{application}.git"
set :branch, "master"


default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup" # keep only the last 5 releases

namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
end


task :after_update_code do  
run "ln -nfs #{deploy_to}/shared/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
end

after :deploy, "assets:precompile"

Error from Capistrano:
executing `deploy:assets:precompile'
  * executing "cd /home/deploy/exigencad/releases/20120621170601 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile"
    servers: ["50.116.25.145"]
    [50.116.25.145] executing command
 ** [out :: 50.116.25.145] rake aborted!
 ** [out :: 50.116.25.145] FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "exigen"
 ** [out :: 50.116.25.145] 
 ** [out :: 50.116.25.145] Tasks: TOP => environment
 ** [out :: 50.116.25.145] 
 ** [out :: 50.116.25.145] (See full trace by running task with --trace)
    command finished in 6433ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
```

Comment: This is all running on a single server, right?

Answer (score 2):

might be totally unrelated to your problem, but since i just hit the same error while running cap deploy:migrate i'll mention it.
did you set host: localhost for your production db in database.yml?
adding that line fixed the problem for me.

Comment: This worked for me. I had the same issue, even rake db:migrate worked on the server; but cap would still fail with "Peer authentication failed"

Answer (score 0):

Try add `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` to your **application.rb** file,that help me.